# How to rename a font in CentOS 6.6?

Tags: centos6

Met a not found 'STSong-Light-UniGB-UCS2-H' font error, I have tried use UMING.ttf to replace it.

I rename the uming.ttf to 'STSong-Light-UniGB-UCS2-H.ttf', and the error was disappear.

But when I install my program on the server which running CentOS 6.6, I place the STSong-Light-UniGB-UCS2-H.ttf in the directory "/usr/share/fonts/TTF" and execute >> fc-cache -fv.

At last the error "not found STSong-Light-UniGB-UCS2-H font" still exist.

Who can help me to give a tip.

Thanks very much.

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sorry. Renamed the uming.ttf to 'STSong-Light-UniGB-UCS2-H.ttf', and the error was disappear. That was debug on Mac.